# Okta java client SDK usage

Tags: java, sdk, client, okta

A have a few questions about okta java SDK, and I couldn't find anything about it in Okta Client SDK:

- I am trying to retrieve user information from okta server. When using the API I make a call to /userinfo endpoint, passing a user token. How could I get this user information using client SDK? I couldn't discover how get user info passing a bearer token.
- How do I get tokens using client SDK ('oauth2/default/v1/token') endpoint (authorization_code, for example)?
- Is there a way to retrive LinkedObjects (https://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/linked-objects) using client SDK?

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Answering the first question (Retrieve user information):

1. Define the client:

```
import com.okta.sdk.client.Client;
import com.okta.sdk.client.Clients;

Client client = Clients.builder()
                        .setOrgUrl(oktaDomain)
                        .setClientCredentials(new TokenClientCredentials(oktaApiToken))
                        .build();

User user = client.getUser(email);
```

This gives you the User object: https://developer.okta.com/okta-sdk-java/development/apidocs/index.html?com/okta/sdk/resource/user/class-use/User.html